# Forms - If text is deleted in input fields user is still able to click submit

Tags: html, css, forms, validation, submit

For my form, if the user enters in all the input fields and then deletes some of these sections they are still able to submit the form.  How can I prevent this from happening?  Any info would be appreciated.

[image: Pic of whats happening]
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/541/)

```
<form id="contact_form" class="container form-hide" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" style="background-color: #00AB8E">
              <label>First Name
                <span class="error">Please enter data.</span>
                <input id="tesFN first_name " maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Last Name
                <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Email
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
                <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Phone
                <span class="error">Please enter a valid phone number</span>              
                <input id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20" type="tel" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>City
                <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>State/Province
                <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label id="co">Company
                <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </label>
              <label>Comments
                <textarea id="comments" name="" id="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"></textarea>
                <input id="sub2" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="SUBMIT"/>
              </label>

                <div>                
                    <select  hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
                    <option  value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
                </select><br>

                <select  hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
                    <option value="">--None--</option>
                    <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
                <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
                <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
                <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
                <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select><br>
                </div>
            </form>

body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  color: #333;

}
input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;

}

input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}


input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Lato;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 15px;
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  border: none;
}

#sub2 {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  border: none;
}


label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: #AB0000;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: #AB0000;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}

input#sub2:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color:  #00AB8E;
}

input#sub:not([disabled]){
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #F68D2E;;
}


#thankyou { display:none;}

#thankyou.success { 
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

#tessellate-page input:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}

#tessellate-page textarea:focus {
    background-color: #fff !important;;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="tel"] {
    background-color: #30bda6;
}

#tessellate-page textarea{
    background-color: #30bda6;
}

#comments_label {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

#cap {
    margin-top: 20px;
}


@media (max-width: 656px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70px;
  }

   .fa {
    transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 656px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }

  label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;

  }


}

label {
    margin-bottom: 48px;
}

function phoneNumber(phone)  {
  var phoneno = /^\d{9,11}$/;

  console.log("PHONE: "+phoneno.test(phone));
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');

  }
});



function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  console.log("email: "+re.test(email));
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");

      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
         $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
  }

});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val()
      && $("#last_name").val()
      && (validateEmail($("#email").val()))
      && (phoneNumber($("#phone").val()))
      && $("#phone").val()
      && $("#city").val()
      && $("#state").val()
      && $("#company").val()
      && $("#comments").val()) {

    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled") && $("#sub2").removeAttr("disabled");
  }
}


 $('#phone').keydown(function(){
   var self = $(this);
   var removedText = self.val().replace(/\D/, '');

   self.val(removedText);
});


$("#contact_form").submit(function(event) {
    console.log("Form success");
    ("#contact_form").
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
})

$("#sub").submit("click", function(e){e.preventDefault()})

$("#sub").on("click", function(e)
{
 $("#contact_form").remove();
 $("#thankyou").addClass("success");
})


$("#sub2").submit("click", function(e){e.preventDefault()})

$("#sub2").on("click", function(e)
{
 $("#contact_form").remove();
 $("#thankyou").addClass("success");
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors in your HTML that are keeping the submit button from working currently. Like `id="tesFN first_name "` - an `id` can only be a single string.

Then you just need to add an `else` condition to your `test()` function to set `$('#sub2').attr('disabled','disabled');`

http://jsfiddle.net/M6N24/543/

```js
function phoneNumber(phone) {
  var phoneno = /^\d{9,11}$/;

  console.log("PHONE: " + phoneno.test(phone));
  return phoneno.test(phone);
}

$('input[type="tel"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#phone')) {
      if (phoneNumber($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");
      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');

  }
});



function validateEmail(email) {
  var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

  console.log("email: " + re.test(email));
  return re.test(email);
}

$('input[type="text"]').on('keyup', function() {
  var $label = $(this).closest('label');
  if ($(this).val().trim() != '') {
    if ($(this).is('#email')) {
      if (validateEmail($(this).val())) {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-times-circle-o").addClass("fa-check-circle");

      } else {
        $label.attr('data-valid', 'error');
        $(this).next("i").removeClass("fa-check-circle").addClass("fa-times-circle-o");
      }
    } else {
      $label.attr('data-valid', 'valid');
    }
  } else {
    $label.removeAttr('data-valid');
  }

});


test = function() {
  if ($("#first_name").val() && $("#last_name").val() && (validateEmail($("#email").val())) && (phoneNumber($("#phone").val())) && $("#phone").val() && $("#city").val() && $("#state").val() && $("#company").val() && $("#comments").val()) {
    $("#sub").removeAttr("disabled") && $("#sub2").removeAttr("disabled");
  } else {
    $("#sub2").attr("disabled", "disabled")
  }
}


$('#phone').keydown(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  var removedText = self.val().replace(/\D/, '');

  self.val(removedText);
});


$("#contact_form").submit(function(event) {
  console.log("Form success");
  ("#contact_form").
  event.preventDefault();
  return false;
})

$("#sub").submit("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
})

$("#sub").on("click", function(e) {
  $("#contact_form").remove();
  $("#thankyou").addClass("success");
})


$("#sub2").submit("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
})

$("#sub2").on("click", function(e) {
  $("#contact_form").remove();
  $("#thankyou").addClass("success");
})
```

```css
body {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #f78e2a;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Lato;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.form-title {
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Lato";
  letter-spacing: 70px;
}

input {
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  margin-top: 8px;
  color: #333;
}

input[type="tel"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  height: 48px;
  color: #333;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
}

input:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="text"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

input[type="tel"]:visited {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f9a558;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Lato;
}

textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff;
}

#co {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

label:nth-last-child(-n+2) {
  flex-basis: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

select,
label {
  height: 50px;
  width: 48%;
  margin: 2% 1%;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: "Lato";
  font-size: 15px;
}

#sub {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  border: none;
}

#sub2 {
  border-radius: 6px;
  width: 120px;
  height: 35px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 48px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: Lato;
  border: none;
}

label {
  position: relative;
}

.fa {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  transform: translate(-50%, 65%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s, color .5s;
}

[data-valid] .fa {
  opacity: 1;
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="valid"] .fa {
  color: #00594C;
}

[data-valid="error"] .fa {
  color: #AB0000;
}

.error {
  display: none;
  color: #AB0000;
  font-size: .7em;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transform: translateY(150%);
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 2px;
}

[data-valid="error"] .error {
  display: block;
}

input#sub2:not([disabled]) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #00AB8E;
}

input#sub:not([disabled]) {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #F68D2E;
  ;
}

#thankyou {
  display: none;
}

#thankyou.success {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}

#tessellate-page input:focus {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  ;
}

#tessellate-page textarea:focus {
  background-color: #fff !important;
  ;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #30bda6;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  color: #333;
}

#tessellate-page input[type="tel"] {
  background-color: #30bda6;
}

#tessellate-page textarea {
  background-color: #30bda6;
}

#comments_label {
  margin-top: 8px;
}

#cap {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

@media (max-width: 656px) {
  label {
    width: 98%;
    height: 70px;
  }
  .fa {
    transform: translate(-50%, -45%);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 656px) {
  .container {
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-self: flex-start;
  }
  label {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
}

label {
  margin-bottom: 48px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="contact_form" class="container form-hide" autocomplete="off" autocomplete="false" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" style="background-color: #00AB8E">
  <label>First Name
    <span class="error">Please enter data.</span>
    <input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Last Name
    <input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Email
    <span class="error">Please enter a valid email address</span>
    <input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Phone
    <span class="error">Please enter a valid phone number</span>
    <input id="phone" maxlength="80" name="phone" size="20" type="tel" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>City
    <input id="city" name="city" maxlength="40" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>State/Province
    <input id="state" maxlength="20" name="state" size="20" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label id="co">Company
    <input id="company" name="company" type="text" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"><i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </label>
  <label>Comments
    <textarea id="comments" name="" cols="30" rows="10" onkeyup="test()" required style="background-color: #30bda6"></textarea>
    <input id="sub2" type="submit" disabled="disabled" value="SUBMIT" />
  </label>

  <div>
    <select hidden="true" id="00N6A000008yXMN" name="00N6A000008yXMN" title="Product Interest">
      <option value="">--None--</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="Visiant">Visiant</option>
      <option value="Tessellate">Tessellate</option>
    </select>
    <br>

    <select hidden="true" id="lead_source" name="lead_source">
      <option value="">--None--</option>
      <option value="Internal">Internal</option>
      <option value="Trade Show">Trade Show</option>
      <option selected="selected" value="Website">Website</option>
      <option value="Direct Marketing">Direct Marketing</option>
      <option value="Social Media">Social Media</option>
      <option value="Other">Other</option>
    </select>
    <br>
  </div>
</form>
```